# Connecting a function with a slot in Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots

As in Qt5, there's a [new signal-slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and I tried utilizing it.

Firstly, I created a `void` return type function:

```
void update()
{
    cerr << "complete";
}
```

And connected it to `&QRadioButton::pressed`

```
QRadioButton *button = new QRadioButton;
QObject::connect(button, &QRadioButton::pressed, update);
```

Things went fine. Afterward, I tried inserting a parameter:

```
void update(bool trigger)
{
    if (!trigger) {return;}
    cerr << "complete";
}
```

And tried connecting:

```
QRadioButton *button = new QRadioButton;
QObject::connect(button, &QRadioButton::toggled(bool), update);
```

But it returned error: `called to non-static member function without an object argument`.

I tried this as well:

```
QObject::connect(button, &QRadioButton::toggled(bool), update(bool));
```

with the same result.

So, how can I patch this? Or, more favorable, how can I implement my function as a slot and get Qt to do the job the old fashion way with `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()`?

Sidenote: I fully understood and also tested the first case (with `void` return type), but I want to know if I ever have to deal with the second case (which will be a lot, actually), what would be a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set the signature since Qt will use the signature of the slot so your initial code should work:

```cpp
QObject::connect(button, &QRadioButton::pressed, update);
```

Comment: I knew that, but I want to know if for whichever reason I have to deal with case 2 (with the parameter) is there a way to resolve the problem? (I edited the post and mentioned it in the sidenote)

Comment: @SilverFox The same connection from case1 works for case2, that's my answer. Have you tried my solution for case 2?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. But well, for some reason if I actually use the parameter for something, maybe like `void updateInc(int i) {a += i;}` (and of course the signal provide an `int`), would the parameter still pass through?

Comment: @SilverFox That code that you show in the comment is not in the post, I think the cause of the problem is another(what is `a`?), so I recommend you create a new post, provide a [MRE]

Comment: Yes, I'm on my way. Thanks for your support.